# WMI - Invalid Class : Win32_InstalledWin32Program

Tags: powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

I have a script that loops through all the workstations from an Active Directory OU and pulls software data from each machine.

I have found two classes that give me this data:

```
Win32_Product
Win32_InstalledWin32Program
```

<s>The latter is the more complete list, since by my understanding, `Win32_Product` only displays apps installed via windows installer, although the latter does not include an InstallDate property. Having an InstallDate is less crucial than having a complete list, so I've been unioning the output of my two `GWMI` commands and using `Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique` to give me close to what I'm looking for.</s>
Edit: Have learned that querying Win32_Product triggers a consistency check for each software it queries, which may reinstall the program if it finds errors. Will be nixing Win32_Product entirely, and thanking whatever divine powers are out there, that I didn’t reinstall some critical production tool.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/974524/event-log-message-indicates-that-the-windows-installer-reconfigured-al

For whatever reason, the `Win32_InstalledWin32Program`class is not available on some computers, and I get an `Get-WMIObject : Invalid Class` error. After checking with `Get-WMIObject` on several of the problem machines, I can confirm that the class I want is not available. ***Why might this be the case, and is there I way I can make it available to me?*** I can't find anything in the documentation about a dependency. All machines are running Windows 7, see screen capture below.

```
      $winProduct = GWMI Win32_Product -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object Name,Vendor,Version,InstallDate
      # vvv This fails on certain machines.
      $winPrograms = GWMI Win32_InstalledWin32Program -ComputerName $computer| Select-Object Name, Vendor, Version, InstallDate
      $winProduct + $winPrograms | Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique | export-csv -path $targetSWfile -notype
```

[image: ProgramQuery Comparison]
[image: OSQuery Comparison]

Comment: Good day! There is a suspicion of wmi damage on this machine. I recommend to restore wmi.

Comment: Can I verify this remotely via powershell, and how might I restore? I understand there are some possible negative implications behind restoring WMI.

I'm new to PS, so I'm not too comfortable playing trial and error at this level, since I'm looping through close to 1000 machines and a fair number have this issue. Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: No, the negative consequences after the recovery wmi did not observe. very often I do it in my office. often machines have to restore wmi and reinstall sccm

Comment: My support group is serviced by very, very many 1000 machines. You can easily find wmi recovery commands on the Internet (now is not at hand, because I'm writing from the phone). We use bat-file for this.

Comment: Good day! Now I'm in my office, so I bring the recovery wmi code. Since it contains many characters, I give it as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

This recovery wmi code, execution from admin or system account:

```
net stop winmgmt
cd %windir%\system32\wbem
if exist Repos_backup rd Repos_backup /s /q
rename Repository Repos_backup
net start winmgmt
winmgmt /resetrepository
winmgmt /salvagerepository
winmgmt /resyncperf
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\System32\scecli.dll
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\System32\userenv.dll
for /f %%s in ('dir /b /s %windir%\System32\wbem\*.dll') do regsvr32 /s %%s
for /f %%s in ('dir /b /s %windir%\System32\wbem\*.exe') do regsvr32 /s %%s
for /f %%s in ('dir /b /s %windir%\System32\wbem\*.mfl') do mofcomp %%s
for /f %%s in ('dir /b /s %windir%\System32\wbem\*.mof') do mofcomp %%s
wmiprvse /regserver
cd %windir%
if exist CCM rd CCM /s /q
if exist ccmcache rd ccmcache /s /q
if exist ccmsetup rd ccmsetup /s /q
if exist SMS*.INI del SMS*.INI /s /q
if exist SMS*.mif del SMS*.mif /s /q
cd %windir%\System32
if exist CCM rd CCM /s /q
if exist ccmcache rd ccmcache /s /q
if exist ccmsetup rd ccmsetup /s /q
```

Comment: what is this? a batch script? pasting this into CMD didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The Win32_InstalledWin32Program class is provided by the file `aeinv.mof`. This file may have become corrupt or missing.

The WMI repository is located here: `C:\Windows\System32\wbem`

One way to resolve this would be to copy the file from a device where the class is working fine and overwrite the file in the problematic device's wmi repo. Subsequently, you'll need to then restart the WinMgmt service.

For more information, see the class definition here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894026(v=vs.85).aspx

In an Enterprise environment this would be relatively unsuitable, and one would assume you'd also have SCCM capturing inventory data. In an Enterprise, it would be more suitable to lean away from these peer-to-peer oriented executions of tasks, and perform Management Server-driven tasks, such as a program from SCCM or some other central administration. How you approach it at scale within an Enterprise comes down to what problem you're actually trying to solve.

There are other mechanisms to retrieve Software inventory, and I would explore that instead of trying to query with Win32_Product or Win32_InstalledWin32Program classes as these are intensive and rely on the client being online at the time of execution.

Comment: It's extremely poor advice to overwrite a file in the Windows folder, and would require admin rights in order to do so. It will also trigger any halfway decent AV software, and (at least in my office) result in administrative action and possible termination.

Comment: The question was: Why might this be the case, and is there I way I can make it available to me?

Comment: And your answer is *replace a file in the Windows folder tree, tripping all AV software on the planet*, which I explained in my previous comment. A bad answer is a bad answer. While it might work, its a bad idea and should be avoided. *Cut off your fingers. That will fix it.* is a bad solution to the problem *My fingernails are too long*, even though it would work.

Comment: Cutting your hand off when your nails are too long, is an analogy fit for describing rebuilding the entire WMI repository when you only have a problem with a single file. This isn't a recommendation for a path forward, it is explicitly answering the question asked. If it were me, I would not be using that WMI class at all.

Comment: FYI - It would not trigger all AV software on the planet. Try to be a little less hysterical in your feedback.

Comment: You're right. Not *all AV software on the planet*. Only those that actually work. There are lots of non-working AV software products (AKA *not real AV software*) that would let it slide. They also let all sorts of malware get on your system. Try to use a little common sense. Every *actually working AV software on the planet* would have a problem with this solution. I had been polite and not voted on your answer. I just changed my mind.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration and time I have updated my answer.

Comment: Appreciate all the insight. The problem in question that I’m trying to solve is that the SCCM probe cannot be installed on all domain workstations. Our enterprise has two separate ISA trees, one governed by IT and one governed by the operations side. The OT machines are out of our jurisdiction however, we are getting flooded with service requests for these outdated assets as the people on the operations team don’t know the difference, and are ill equipped to provide the support themselves.

Comment: The business has asked for a data analytics solution to view enterprise hardware and software inventory; specifically to compare IT vs OT assets in order to gauge the need for an on-site specialist to maintain these assets, or to place them under IT jurisdiction. Some of these OT assets are completely off limits, so I’ve been tasked with coming up with a remote non-invasive query to gather this data, as a domain admin. To get consistent data, I’ve  had to avoid SCCM altogether. If you have an alternative solution to my problem, definitely would appreciate guidance.

Comment: Assuming they are within the same domain, you could consider adding a collection in SCCM particularly forthis demographic that is out of your jurisdiction. That collection would then need client settings applied to it that removed any and all deployment related activities, and only performed inventory collection. That way the data can be aggregated & consumed via SCCM but the devices remain untouched by SCCM. Does that sound like a plausible solution? It would require installing the agent, but ensuring they received a completely different policy set (for users & computers).

Comment: This could be done if they were also in another domain with an appropriate trust relationship. This can be done "non-invasively", besides the part where an agent gets installed :)

Comment: That was my initial thought, but unfortunately no, the agent cannot be installed. Some of these machines are dedicated to one specific task, as in they run 24/7 displaying production metrics and are critical to the business. These machines are also coming up, if not surpassing, 10 years old, hence the question of how to deal with them. SCCM would be the cleanest option, of course, but I’m hoping not the only one.

Comment: For devices running 24/7, you can absolutely do a direct query if that's the only suitable way beyond using out-of-the-box tools (SCCM). There are functions out there you can leverage so as to avoid using those 2 WMI classes - by instead scraping registry keys for example. Look into how you can query Win32 application installs without using WMI. Then for those that aren't on 24/7, you really do need an Agent-Server relationship if you want 100% coverage, or you may be trying to query offline devices for weeks. I personally would push for the CM agent... I don't envy your predicament!

Comment: Here's an example of not using the WMI classes - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software/

Comment: Be sure to read through the comments! There's more really good information in there.